# Conditional Annotation doesn't get triggered

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to use `@Conditional` annotation and but the `Condition` class doesn't seem to be triggered. I'm trying to use this on an annotation.

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = CheckIdValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Conditional(value=CheckIdCondition.class)
public @interface CheckId {
    String message() default "has invalid format";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

CheckIdCondition class

```
public class CheckIdCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I try to trigger this using the exisiting tests(also with a debug point), this doesn't reach and the old tests pass. So it doesn't work for sure. How can I fix this

Comment: Where are you using the `@CheckId` annotation?

Comment: I didn't understand where do you put this custom `@CheckId` annotation exactly. And how is it related to tests? Tests are powered by junit/testng, and this annotation extends the spring framework. Can you show an example of test in the question?

Comment: could you please share your test case

Comment: @CheckId is a field level annotation. w.r.t the tests, the other custom validatiors get triggered, so the type of test shouldn't really matter here.